# Dropdown menu not working Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My dropdown menu suddenly stopped working.  The only change I can think of that I made was to run `rake assets:precompile`, and now the JS on the site is screwy.

Here is the dropdown that isn't working (rendered HTML):

```
  <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="logofont">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li  id="blacklink" class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Login <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="blacklink"><a href="/login">For Drivers</a></li>
    <li id="blacklink"><a href="/shoplogin">For Businesses</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
  </ul>
```

I'm also having issues with a button on a create.js form that creates an object through jQuery without reloading, but is now creating two every time.  All this without changes to my code. Could someone give me an idea of what I could look at?  No idea how to troubleshoot this.

Here's that create.js

```
<% if @car.errors.present? %> 
    $('#error_messages').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shared/error_messages', object: @car) %>");
<% else %>
    if($('#car_feed ul').length == 0){
        $('#car_feed').html("<ul class=cars></ul>")
    }
    $('#car_feed ul').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'cars/car', car: @car) %>");
<% end %>
```

for the form

```
<%= form_for(@car, html: {multipart: true, remote: true}) do |f| %>
  <h3> Add Your Car</h3>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :year, placeholder: "Year i.e. '1993" %>
    <%= f.text_area :brand, placeholder: "Brand i.e. 'Ford'"%>
    <%= f.text_area :model, placeholder: "Model i.e. 'Mustang'" %>
    <%= f.text_area :vin, placeholder: "17 digit VIN number" %>
    <%= f.text_area :mileage, placeholder: "Current Car Mileage" %>
  </div>
  <p> Add a Photo </p>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
  <div id="error_messages">
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add Car", class: "btn btn-add btn-primary" %>
  <button class="btn btn-hide btn-primary"> Hide Form </button>
  <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#car_picture').bind('change', function() {
    size_in_megabytes = this.files[0].size/1024/1024;
    if (size_in_megabytes > 5) {
      alert('Maximum file size is 5MB. Please choose a smaller file.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: if you run `rake assets:clobber` (which will delete the compiled assets) does it work?

Comment: No. Tried resetting public/assets another way too.  Is there some way to troubleshoot this to find an error or something I can work with?

Comment: can you please open the browser debug window, navigate to the console part and refresh the page? this might produce `js` errors and sent you on the right track. Please let us know the result

Comment: There were no errors in debug when I reloaded the page with the console open